# Selecting features of layer based on meeting length requirements within another layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, select

I'm trying to select roads from one line layer, where 1/3 of their miles are within another polygon layer.

I can't figure out the logic necessary, such as Select * from route_data Where (1/3 of their length?) are within Population_blocks layer.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a long field to store the Object ID of each line and a double field to store the original length of each line, then run the Intersect tool to divide the line by the polygons wit the output to a file geodatabase feature class of polylines.  Then select the lines with line lengths >= original length / 3 and perform a relate back to the original line feature class on the field holding the original Object ID.

Comment: If we can't assume lines cross into/out of the polygon more than twice, I suppose we'd need to summarize on original ObjectID ... or does intersect create multi-part polyline features?

Comment: It creates multi-part polylines for each polygon intersected.  So you do not need to summarize on the ObjectID after using the Intersect tool.  If you actually wanted each portion of the line that crossed the polygon to be a separate line feature you would have to use the Multipart to Singlepart tool after using Intersect to get that result.